# How to use type switch to change css in PrestaShop 1.7 forms

Tags: php, css, forms, prestashop-1.7

I want a type switch to change value in css class but type switch does not support custom values then 1 and 0? how to do it?

```
   'input' => array(
    'type' => 'switch',
    'label' => $this->l('backgrounds'),
    'name' => 'test',
    'options' => array(
    'query' => $test,
          'id' => 'id_option',
          'name' => 'name'
        )
    )
),

    $test = array(
        array(
            'id_option' => '#header {background: #ffffff;}',
            'name' => $this->l('white bg')
        ),
        array(
            'id_option' => '#header {background: #333333;}',
            'name' => $this->l('dark bg')
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For type 'switch' you have to use 'values' instead of 'options'.

This is example from default PrestaShop module :

```
    $input = array(
        'type' => 'switch',
        'label' => $this->trans('Newsletter', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'),
        'name' => 'newsletter',
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 't',
        'is_bool' => true,
        'value' => $newsletter,
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'newsletter_on',
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => $this->trans('Enabled', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 'newsletter_off',
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => $this->trans('Disabled', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            )
        ),
        'hint' => $this->trans('This customer will receive your newsletter via email.', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Help'),
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, i saw this myself, but still don't get it how to make it work

Comment: If you edit your first post and explain what your goal is and what it is going to do, it's better to be guided.

Comment: um, i'm doing form as it said, and the form is collecting mainly css valuablues with type colors and write them in css file. However i want to include a type switch for a basic css classes like on "Enabled" in the switch css class #header {background: #000) and on disabled #header {background: #fff) and get those value and put it in other array for output with something like "#header {
    background-color: ' . Tools::getValue('header') . ';
} That's why i included the second array i thought its clear

Answer (score 0):

I think switch is only supporting "On"/"Off" and "Yes/No" values - you could try to change the following logic in form.tpl but it seems to be easier to use another type instead

```
<label {if $value.value == 1} for="{$input.name}_on"{else} for="{$input.name}_off"{/if}>
    {if $value.value == 1}
        {l s='Yes' d='Admin.Global'}
    {else}
        {l s='No' d='Admin.Global'}
    {/if}
</label>
```